# Why does Flask server avoids specific port opening?

Tags: python, flask

When I specify an IP and port without the preceding:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

As such:

```
app.run(host="138.165.91.210",port=5017,threaded=True)
```

It works but it hangs a bit (does it hang on an infinite loop maybe?). When I do the usual:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="138.165.91.210",port=5017,threaded=True)
```

It avoids the ip and port. What's wrong with my code?

Full script:

```
import os
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
     render_template, flash


# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__)


# Load default config and override config from an environment variable



def connect_db():
    """Connects to the specific database."""
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv


def init_db():
    """Initializes the database."""
    db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit()


@app.cli.command('initdb')
def initdb_command():
    """Creates the database tables."""
    init_db()
    print('Initialized the database.')


def get_db():
    """Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
    current application context.
    """
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    """Closes the database again at the end of the request."""
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()


@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)


@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('insert into entries (title, text) values (?, ?)',
               [request.form['title'], request.form['text']])
    db.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME']:
            error = 'Invalid username'
        elif request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
            error = 'Invalid password'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="138.165.91.210",port=5017,threaded=True)
```

Edit:

I'm running the app using `bash`:

```
flask --app=flaskr run
```

Comment: How are you running the app?

Comment: Take a note that `__name__` == 'main' only if script is run directly.

Comment: @dirn from bash: flask --app=flaskr run

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov what does it mean?

Comment: Recommended reading: [What does `if __name__ == “__main__”:` do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: It means that block inside if statement works only if you do `python application.py`

Answer (score 1):

> You are using an unreleased version of Flask, so keep in mind that things might change.

`__name__ == '__main__'` only evaluates to True when you execute a file directly (i.e., `python filename.py`). Since that isn't how you're running it here, it will be False and that block is skipped.

To solve your port issue, when running your application using the `flask` command, you need to specify your options through the command line.

```
python -m flask --app flaskr --host 138.165.91.210 --port 5017 --with-threads
```

For more information, you should check the usage

```
python -m flask --help
```

To solve your delay issue, the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block is important. Without it, Flask will try to run two instances of the application (once from the `flask` command and one from the call to `app.run`).